# python: mocking tapioca wrapper

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Still new to python and especially writing python unit tests.

Found http://tapioca-wrapper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ and wrote a simple client around an api.

The module essentially takes the key/value pairs of a api's payload and converts them into objects.  Since this is dynamic and generated by the payload, I'm having a hard time with the best approach in writing mock unittest.

Sample wrapper code is:

```
api_client = APIClientAdapter()
vm_machine = api_client.vm_machine(vm_name='playdohvm').get()
print("vm name: {}".format(vm_machine.name().data)
```

My mock code looks like

```
self.mock_api_client = Mock(
    spec=APIClientAdapter,
    return_value=Mock(
        get=Mock(
            return_value=Mock(
                name=Mock(
                    return_value=Mock(
                        data='playdohvm'))))))
```

Is this there a better way to mock tapioca-wrapper module?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to test, I think that it will change how mock should be made.

For example, without having to express everything with a Mock object, it is good to prepare a simple object and replace it with `mock.patch`.

```
class DummyAPIClientAdapter:

    data = 'playdohvm'

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self
    def __getattr__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self

with mock.patch('APIClientAdapter', new=DummyAPIClientAdapter):
    api_client = APIClientAdapter()
    vm_machine = api_client.vm_machine(vm_name='playdohvm').get()
    print("vm name: {}".format(vm_machine.name().data))
```